# In plant cells, is water stored only in the vacuole?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, eukaryotic-cells

In the turgor of plant cells, is water stored only in the vacuole or can it be stored in the cytoplasm and the other cellular organs too?

Answer (score 1):

One of the properties of "storoge" is that in can be filled or empied when needed. Contents of cytoplasm and all organelles are aqueous solutions so all of them contain quite some water. However, thease solutions need to maintain precise concentration of many solutes in order to facilitate proper enviroment for various biological processes. Therefore, radical changes in amount of water in cytoplasm would be detrimental to life of the cell. Vacuole is not as sensitive and it can expand or shrink and act as a sort of water availibility buffer for the rest of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

The cytoplasm of the cell is 80% water$^1$. All organelles contain water because all enzymatic activities inside the cell require water. However vacuoles are generally said to **store** water because they generally make up 30% to 80%$^2$ of the plant cell.

Thus the cytoplasm, vacuole and all other organelles contain water and contribute to the cells water potential and turgor pressure.

References:

1.[Wikipedia cytoplasm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cytoplasm)

2.[Wikipedia vacuole](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuole)